# Swift loading JSON in extension of struct

Tags: swift, struct, jsondecoder

Given this (partially pasted) struct:

```
struct InstrumentsSet: Identifiable, Decodable {

    static func withJSON(_ fileName: String) -> InstrumentsSet? {
        guard let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: fileName, withExtension: "json", subdirectory: "Sets") else { return nil }
        guard let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url) else { return nil }
        return try? JSONDecoder().decode(InstrumentsSet.self, from: data)
    }
    
    let name: String
    let bpm: Double
    let timeSignature: Int
    var tracks: [Track]
}
```

And this extension:

```
extension InstrumentsSet {
    
    struct Track: Identifiable, Decodable {
        
        static func withJSON(_ fileName: String) -> InstrumentsSet.Track? {
            guard let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: fileName, withExtension: "json", subdirectory: "Sets") else { return nil }
            guard let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url) else { return nil }
            
            //At this point data has the JSON loaded and decode makes it jump to the fatal error located at the call
            return try? JSONDecoder().decode(InstrumentsSet.Track.self, from: data)
        }
    
        let instrumentType: InstrumentType
        let startType: StartType
    }
}
```

I can load successfully an instrument set from JSON with nested Tracks this way:

```
guard var instrumentSet1 = InstrumentsSet.withJSON("file-with-set") else {
    fatalError("Error loading set JSON")
}
```

Next I'd like to add a track to the existing set by loading a json with just Track data:

```
guard let masterTrack = InstrumentsSet.Track.withJSON("file-with-track") else {
    fatalError("Error loading track JSON")
}
```

When running this part I can see the JSON data loading successfully, but on this line `return try? JSONDecoder().decode(InstrumentsSet.Track.self, from: data)` the fatalError is triggered without further explanation. My guess is something is missing in the instrumentSet part since the function "InstrumentsSet.Track.withJSON" is called through the original InstrumentsSet struct so passing down just a track is not possible?

My question, given the struct and its extension, is it possible to load just the extension part (Track) of the struct into the `let masterTrack`?

Example Set JSON:

```
{
    "name": "Set name",
    "bpm": 124.00,
    "timeSignature": 4,
    "tracks": [
        {
            "instrumentType": "exsSampler",
            "startType": "trigger"
        }
    ]
}
```

Example Track JSON. (I've tried passing this as an Array, but still no success)

```
{
    "instrumentType": "audioBuffer",
    "startType": "global"
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: use try-catch to get the exact error. also track is array so try this ```[InstrumentsSet.Track].self```

Comment: There is no *further explanation* because **you** ignore the error which would give you a pretty comprehensive error message. By the way you should get a compiler error that your structs don't conform to `Identifiable `

Comment: This looks like an overcomplicated solution to me, make withJSON a standalone and generic function so you don't have to duplicate code.

Comment: Thank you, I've got an error now ""Expected to decode Dictionary<String, Any> but found an array instead." I've got something to work on now

Comment: Solved, I learned "fatalError" will suppress all debugging info. The problem was a difference in CodingKeys and the actual JSON. Thank you @vadian for your helpful support.